# What does #__ mean at the beginning of a table name in a Joomla mysql query?

Tags: mysql, joomla, query-builder

I have a mysql query that looks like this `$query="SELECT * FROM #__content"`.

What does the `#__` at the start of the table name mean?

Comment: please add the full code you are using to pull data from the database. `$query="SELECT * FROM #__content"` isn't enough to go by

Comment: @US-Samurai https://docs.joomla.org/Database_Table_Prefix and https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_your_database_prefix and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54623056/2943403

Answer (score 1):

`#__` is a prefix of your tables

Comment: Thank you, what about my second question please ?

Answer (score 1):

`#__` is simply the database table prefix and is defined in you configuration.php

If it wasn't defined, people would have to manually have to input their prefixes into every extension that requires access to the database, which you can imagine would be annoying.

So for example, if you database table prefix is `j25`, then:

`#__content` = `j25_content`

Comment: But if I use mysql command prompt to run that query, it says that i am making an sql error syntax

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, hash underscore sequence '#_' is the prefix used for table names by Joomla!'s JDatabase class. (*N.B. there is only one underscore, the second underscore is maintained to for readability in table names.)*

When you first setup Joomla! you are given the option of setting a prefix or using the one randomly generated at the time. You can read about [how to check the prefix here](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_determine_your_database_prefix).

When you access the database using the JDatabase class it provides you with an abstraction mechanism so that you can interact with the database that Joomla is using without you having to code specifically for MySQL or MSSQL or PostgreSQL etc.

When JDatabase prepares a query prior to executing it, it replaces any occurrences `#_` in the `from` segment of the query with the prefix setup when Joomla! was installed. e.g.

```
    // Get the global DB object.        
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    // Create a new query object.       
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    // Select some fields
    $query->select('*');

    // Set the from From segment
    $query->from('#__myComponents_Table');
```

Later when you execute the query JDatabase will change the `from` segment of the SQL from

`from #__myComponents_Table` to

`from jp25_myComponents_Table` — if the prefix is `jp25`, prior to executing it.