# php or mysql pound underscore variable

Tags: mysql

Ran across some old PHP code that runs as a mysql query that I need to debug because its failing.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM #__menu ORDER BY name";
```

Basically I have never seen a pound symbol in PHP or MySQL used like this. I could understand if it was a comment or a super global variable but I don't think it is that.

Comment: Maybe this thread is relevant, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048505/mysql-data-query-and-the-sharp-pound-underbar-thing.

Comment: Backtick the table name, `\`#__menu\``, if that's the literal name of your table. If `#__` is meant to stand in for a table prefix (presumably this is old Joomla stuff), then substitute it as necessary before running the query. If that doesn't answer, post some surrounding code so we have a context for what's happening here.