# Syntax error on table name in mysql query

Tags: php, joomla, query-builder

I'm unable to reference a database **view** in a Joomla article using php code. Though I am able to access a table, I'm unable to reference a view. Please note that the data is stored in MySQL using phpMyAdmin. Below is my code where the **view name** is jos2_vw_member_contribution.

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('Recipient','Target', 'Actuals'))));
$query->from($db->quoteName('jos2_vw_member_contribution'));
$query->setOrder('Recipient','ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
?>
```

The above throws an error
**1146 - Table '.#__vw_member_contribution' doesn't exist.**

Your early help is appreciated to the above problem. Also, I strongly urge **not** to use this thread to discuss the pros and cons of the view vs. table usage.

Thanks,
Paippad.

Comment: I am not a programmer but your parentheses are mismatched at `$query->select($db->quoteName(array('Recipient','Target', 'Actuals'))));`

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with [Joomla's Coding Standards](https://developer.joomla.org/coding-standards/php-code.html) (Section labeled: **SQL Queries**), you should not be literally naming the table "prefix", you should use `#__`.  (Though your error indicates that you are using `#__`.)

That pesky little `.` in front of your table name looks troublesome.  You'd better check that your table name is precisely: `#__vw_member_contribution` in your php.

`->setOrder()` is going to silently kill your query because it is not a query method (resource: https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html), you should be using `order()`

Suggested untested snippet with diagnostics and error catching:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('Recipient','Target','Actuals')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__vw_member_contribution'))
    ->order($db->quoteName('Recipient'));  // ASC is the default direction

JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("<div>Rendered Select Query:<br>" . $query->dump() . "</div>", 'notice');  // don't show to public

try
{
    $db->setQuery($query);
    if (!$results = $db->loadObjectList())  // declare and check $result
    {
        echo "No matches found";
    }
    else
    {
        // do your thing with $result
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // don't show to the public
}
```

p.s. When you have Joomla questions, please post them at [Joomla Stack Exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) to receive valuable feedback from volunteers with intimate expertise with Joomla.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue. I hope I had made it clear in my original post that there was no issue in accessing data from a table. The issue occurs only when accessing data from a **view**.

Comment: The syntax errors in your posted code made that difficult to believe. I guess we'll need to see more of your code in that file.  Better if you post your question on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.